# PHP Setting a SESSION Variable Name Using A Variable

Tags: php, session, variables, names

I would like to set the name of a $_SESSION variable to be the value of another variable.
e.g.

```
$var = "123";
$_SESSION['$var'] = "yes";

echo $_SESSION['123'];  // Would like to echo "yes"
echo $_SESSION['$var'];  // Would also like to echo "yes"
```

I performed a vardump($_SESSION) and the session variable is literally set to "$_SESSION[$var]". How can I achieve the result I require?

Many Thanks.

Comment: It works [almost] exactly like an "array" .. read up on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ditch the single quotes. They make PHP parse the $ as a literal dollar sign instead of the beginning of a variable name.

```
$_SESSION['$var'] = "yes";
```

should be:

```
$_SESSION[$var] = "yes";
```

Comment: Or could be in double quotes of he really wants to keep the quotes or have to do concatenation (eg prefix to name)

Comment: Thanks so much. A silly error tbh. Maybe it's time to stop coding and get some sleep. lol. Thanks again.